# How Do I Initialize an Existing Microsoft SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, initialization, reset

I have a database which has users assigned against it. I want to initialize the database (as though I'd just created it) rather than creating a new one, naming it appropriately, and re-adding all of the users.

1. Is it possible to completely reinitialize/reset a database?
2. Is it possible to do (1) whilst retaining the users and their permissions?

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate script to create SQL file with Schema and user information.
Rename the existing db and run the script to create new one. Generate script provides lot of options to customize the script according to your needs

1. Right click on db -> Tasks -> Generate script -> Click next on the
   wizard
2. Enable 'script logins' in  Choose script options section of
   the wizard
3. Select the users
4. Generate the script

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That creates a script to generate the users which is useful but I still need to initialize the existing database rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Once I've initialized the existing database, I can at least re-add the users using your approach.

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Do you want to delete the data in all tables?

Comment: I want to be able to initialise the database to the same state as it was when I first created it. As an example, I create my database, run a script to create all of the tables and data I need, and then encounter an error. It's at this point that I'd like to initialise the database, edit my script and then re-run it. I've always been surprised that there isn't a (verified) option to reset a database at the same UX level as creating and deleting one.